# How to protect against your patent attorney stealing your ideas?

Tags: patent-infringement, attorney, idea, lawyers, first-to-file

So in order for me to file a patent for my ideas, I need to hire a patent attorney to write up the documents etc.

This means that I must thoroughly reveal and describe my ideas to my attorney.

How do I prevent the attorney from stealing those ideas and claiming that its his/hers?

Comment: It just doesn’t happen. They would be risking their entire career they have spent years to achieve on the potential of your invention. I’m betting that your invention isn’t remotely worth it.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite What about the possibility of them telling my ideas to their relatives and friends.

Comment: Again, they would risk their careers. I’ve never heard of it happening.

Comment: If you convey any of this type of concern to a patent attorney they would be unlikely to be motivated to work with you. Many will not take on independent inventors at all. Some will work with independent inventors who they perceive as relatively sophisticated consumers of legal services with realistic expectations.

Comment: The real results of hiring an attorney may more likely be quite the other way around. The questions that a committed attorney will ask you are likely to give you reason to reflect, and the more searching they are, the more likely it is you may well respond by making changes that improve the invention, or its scope of coverage, as a result. I don't know of any attorney who would do anything other than regard that as part of the professional and confidential service -- I certainly never heard of any who would in a million years claim to be  a co-inventor!!